# Not receiving any emails from my form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, forms

So I have this problem with my form, I'm using XAMPP and WAMP to test if I had written my PHP file well, everything works except the fact that I'm not receiving any emails. I'm not quite sure what's the matter, so if anyone could be so kind to help me with this, I would be most grateful.

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label class="titulo-celeste" for="nombre" style="font-weight:normal;">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label class="titulo-celeste" for="correo"style="font-weight:normal;">Email</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label class="titulo-celeste" for="asunto"style="font-weight:normal;">Asunto</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" name="asunto">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><br>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label class="titulo-celeste" for="mensaje"style="font-weight:normal;">Mensaje</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><br>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-eiger pull-right">Enviar</button>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

and Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = 'carlosxg87@gmail.com';

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['nombre'], "No sabemos tú nombre");
$subject = check_input($_POST['asunto'], "No escribiste el Asunto");
$email = check_input($_POST['correo']);
$message = check_input($_POST['mensaje'], "Te falto añadir tu Mensaje");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Tú dirección de correo no es válida");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Nombre: $name
Correo: $email
Asunto: $subject

Mensaje:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <title>EIGER - Escuela Internacional de Gerencia</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<body class="background-light-grey">
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center" style="margin-top:10%;">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block">
    <h3 class="titulo-celeste">Por favor corrige el siguiente error:</h3>
    <h1 class="titulo-azul"><strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong></h1>
    <p>Intenta una vez más</p>
    <a href="contacto.html#formulario"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Regresar</button></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: First thing to do: Check the return value of `mail()`. Is it `true` or `false`? You should also not redirect until you've got the php part sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated your SMTP server in your php.ini file? Windows does not usually have a smtp server running, so you likely have to specify an external one.

You need to find the SMTP parameter and set it to your smtp server:

```
SMTP = smtp.domain.com
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php